Split a CSV file with different section and column headers in django models
Please i'm a newbie in python, I have a CSV file with this type of structure. How do i split this csv after uploading and create or update my django database with the data for model.
About
no,name,shape,type
1,John,circle,metal
..................
..................

Address
no,street,postcode,city,County
1,peel,sd1 q23,london,east london
...............................

about 9 sections, a major section header which could be ignored while parsing into the database, the first row are headers, and data for each column
I was able to create a model and import data from a single row of headers into my model. I've tried using row.get('title') to split the csv file but it's not working. I can't find any example directly related to this yet. thanks

why not split the csv into each of their smaller csv counter parts based on the section header, which could could likely do by trying to read the file line by line and finding those lines that only have 1 value in it (or no commas) to split the file into these subparts

what do you use to read CSV? With standard module csv it can be problem to split it but with pandas it can be simpler. But first problem - if you have many tables/sections in one file then it is NOT csv file. CSV should have only one table without section's name. You will have to split it on empty like and remove lines About and Address

So I was able to split the csv files and parse into my django models by doing this:
def import_and_process_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        data_set = ()
        new_dataset = request.FILES['csv_file']
        
        
        if not new_dataset.name.endswith('csv'):
            messages.info(request,'wrong format')
            return render(request,'import.html')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'File uploaded successfully')

       
        csv_content = new_dataset.read().decode('utf-8')
        

        # Use io.StringIO to create a file-like object from the string content
        csv_string_io = io.StringIO(csv_content)
        next(csv_string_io)
        
        data_set = csv.reader(csv_string_io, delimiter=',')
        

        #Read the data for rows in store and parse into models.
        specific_values = ['biscuit']
        printed_rows_indices = set()

    # Iterate over each specific value
        for desired_value in specific_values:
        # Initialize a flag to track if the desired row value is found
            found_row_value = False

        # Initialize a list to store rows before the desired value
            rows_before_desired_value1 = []

            for index, row in enumerate(data_set):
            # Check if the desired value is found in the current row
                if desired_value in row:
                    found_row_value = True
                    break
                # Stop the CSV reader when the desired value is found
                         
                rows_before_desired_value1.append(row)  #rows before Biscuit
            next
        
                
            for i,column in enumerate(rows_before_desired_value1):
                
                if i !=0:                   
                    if column and not all(element == ',' for element in column):  # Check if the list is not empty and not comma-only
                                        
                        if len(column) > 0:                     
                            myModel.objects.update_or_create(
                            My_Object1 =  column[0],
                            My_Object2 = column[1],
                            
                    )
                                
    return render(request,'import.html')


